# RF Antenna design for 2 different operating frequencies

Tags: rf

I have noticed that my mobile phone sometimes shows it is using the 3G and then other times the 4G.

How is that possible if they are using the same antenna?

I assume it would use a microcontroller to switch the path going to the antenna to have the correct impedance (50 ohm). Or perhaps a Balun that can manage the different frequencies?

3G - 1.8 GHz

4G - 2.6 GHz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining papers from Broadcom Corp, some years back, on all-silicon radios (no offchip discretes), they were using Varactors to **TUNE** the antenna interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is worse than that.  I'm not sure where you're getting the source data, but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_frequencies_in_the_US) a 4G phone in the US would need to cover 600MHz to 5.6GHz.

There are a number of ways to skin that cat.  I'm not sure what's prevalent in the cell phone world.

- Use a wideband antenna, such as a log spiral.
- Use sorta-wideband antennas and tune them by switching in resonators.
- Use multiple antennas with passive diplexers.
- Use dual-band antennas (if it's a dual-band radio).
- Use bespoke antennas for the service provider; i.e., a Verizon phone could just cover the Verizon frequencies, a Sprint phone could just cover the Sprint frequencies, etc.
- Use multiple antennas with one RF section, as you suggest.
- Use multiple RF sections each with its own antennas.

I suspect wideband antennas, but I'm willing to be educated.

Base stations would have fewer frequencies to deal with, and a bigger budget both for money spent and space used.